# Using backslashes properly with Echo

Tags: php

I am trying to echo a variable that contains a `'`, however it broke the script. To fix this, I used `addslashes();`

This is my code

```
$row["market_hash_name"] = addslashes($row["market_hash_name"]);
echo  $row["market_hash_name"];
```

Now this doesn't break the script, but displays a backslash. How can i not make it display a backslash before the `'` without the `'` breaking the script.

Edit: I understand it does not break the script, however, it prevents the rest of the jQuery echoed by the php from working properly.

Comment: Are you sure echoing the variable containing the `'` is what broke the script? What does `$row["market_hash_name"]` contain? What was the error that you got?

Comment: It contains some text such as `don't` and I am sure this broke the script

Comment: you can use `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `addslashes()` however, the best way is to use prepared statements.  Not only do you not need to avoid remembering to escape every variable, you are protecting against mot sql injections

Comment: @Semger It doesn't break the script. That's MySQL query which has to be escaped twice ( one for current php script and one for mysql )

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: having to use it multiple times, is exactly why to use prepared statements.   MUCH less work.  MUCH more secure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($row["market_hash_name"], ENT_QUOTES);
```

It will make sure all special characters are converted to HTML entities, so a single quote becomes `&#039;`

Answer (score 1):

It won't be breaking, if you are just echoing

```
$row = array(
    'market_hash_name' => "hello'world"
);

echo $row['market_hash_name']; // outputs: hello'world
```

Answer (score 0):

Echoing the word `don't` doesn't break your script and you can easily echo it **when it is stored in a variable** but if you want to echo a word without storing it somewhere it needs to be escaped using htmlspecialchars()

I think you have been confused with query and html output. **In a query you escape a string twice.** for example:

```
$query = 'I don\'t think so.';
               ^ first escape for php script
$query = 'I don\\\'t think so.';
                ^ second escape for mysql
```

it goes to mysql like this: `I don\'t think so.`
Also you can use different types of quotations to avoid this 2 step escaping. like:

`"I don't think so.";`

`'I don"t think so.';`